# Xor logic in python

Tags: python, performance, bitwise-xor

I have solved this problem from hackerearth.com using python(v2)

Problem statement: [Xor is Mad](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/bit-manipulation/basics-of-bit-manipulation/practice-problems/algorithm/xor-is-mad-77/)

My code is :

```
tests = int(raw_input())
for i in range(tests):
x = int(raw_input())
c = 0
b = x
a = x-1
while a > 0:
    xor = a^b
    summ =  b + a
    # print "XOr : ",xor
    # print "Sum : ",summ,"\n--------"
    if xor == summ:
        c += 1
        a -= 1
    elif a > 0:
        a -= 1 
print c
```

but I have time exceeding problem for inputs : input#5 to #9

can somebody solve this problem in different way to manage the tests to be executed in 1sec.

Comment: Could you give us some of the tests?  What inputs is your code slow for?

Comment: Hi @PatrickHaugh, you can submit this answer on hacker there and check for input#5 to #9.. Actually they are providing test files which contain 10K-100k lines. can you please get some time for this.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to recognize that you don't have to test all the `a` up to `x`.  For `a^x == a+x`, then `a&x == 0`.  So we count the number of zeroes in the bitstring of `x` and then out answer is `2**count -1`

```
test = int(input())
for _ in range(test):
    x = int(input())
    print(2**bin(x)[2:].count('0') -1)
```